# What is Date_Spec in sudoers policy?

Tags: linux, security, sudo

I was reading through the sudoers policy manual. Under 'User specification' section, I saw `Date_Spec` as part of the `Option_Spec`, in turn an optional part of the `Cmnd_Spec`.

```
 User_Spec ::= User_List Host_List '=' Cmnd_Spec_List \
               (':' Host_List '=' Cmnd_Spec_List)*

 Cmnd_Spec_List ::= Cmnd_Spec |
                    Cmnd_Spec ',' Cmnd_Spec_List

 Cmnd_Spec ::= Runas_Spec? Option_Spec* Tag_Spec* Cmnd

 Runas_Spec ::= '(' Runas_List? (':' Runas_List)? ')'

 Option_Spec ::= (Date_Spec | Timeout_Spec)

 Date_Spec ::= ('NOTBEFORE=timestamp' | 'NOTAFTER=timestamp')

 Timeout_Spec ::= 'TIMEOUT=timeout'
```

What does this do? From my reading, it looks like something I can use to restrict the time span within which a user can run a command. Is that correct? If so, what are the possible use cases for such a feature?

Ref: `man 5 sudoers`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for the Date_Spec appears to have been added in version [1.8.20](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.20/sudoers.man.html), with the [Changelog](https://www.sudo.ws/changes.html) indicating that it the code was changed by 2017-02-18:

> Add NOTBEFORE and NOTAFTER command options similar to what is already available in LDAP.

The option does exactly as you guessed: restricts the corresponding rule to have a start and/or end date.

For example, I added this rule:

```
jeff2 ALL=(ALL) NOTBEFORE=20190409212700 /bin/ps
```

and then executed the following as `jeff2`:

```
$ sudo -l
# ... elided ...
User jeff2 may run the following commands on r2d2:
    (ALL) /bin/ls
    (ALL) NOTBEFORE=20190410012700Z /bin/ps
$ date -u '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
20190410 01:25:52
$ sudo /bin/ps
Sorry, user jeff2 is not allowed to execute '/bin/ps' as root on r2d2.
$ sleep 2m   ## plus get distracted by something
$ date -u '+%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S'
20190410 01:29:33
$ sudo /bin/ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9607 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

I can see a use-case for this where you want to grant temporary additional access (say for a specific application upgrade or change), but you don't want to have to remember to log in before and after that timeframe to update sudoers. Perhaps you have a privileged user that's changing roles and no longer needs certain commands after a certain date; you could use `NOTAFTER` at your convenience, then go in later and delete the rules at some point later. Similarly with `NOTBEFORE` for someone changing roles into one that is a more privileged.

Comment: Thanks, I'm also assuming you can do this to multiple commands? Like `jeff2` can't run `ps` after Monday and he can't run `ping` after Tuesday? I wonder why this is feature is not more popular. Seems like a handy thing. I need to read the man page more carefully and understand this better.

Comment: Correct in your assumption; the Date_Spec is part of the Option_Spec which is part of the Cmnd_Spec, which is a comma-separated list of "commands", so `ps` could have a different Date_Spec than `ping`, for your example.  I have not yet seen Date_Spec in the wild, myself, maybe because that feature is relatively new (in the non-LDAP world). In fact, I had to compile a newer version of sudo on that Debian "stable" VM in order to test my Answer.

Comment: I'm about to test this in Debian 9. Date_Spec is not in the default compile options?

Comment: The [sudo version in Stretch:stable](https://packages.debian.org/stable/admin/) is 1.8.19p1, which predates the introduction of Date_Spec in 1.8.20 by just a few months. Unstable has v1.8.27.

Comment: Hold on, isn't `sudoers` a policy plugin for `sudo`? How's that dependent on `sudo` itself? I thought the onus of implementation was on the plugin itself.

Comment: Oh crap! The plugin is at version parity with `sudo` 

`user@debian:~$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.19p1
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.19p1
Sudoers file grammar version 45
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.19p1`